# TidHttp and XE3

Tags: delphi, http, indy, delphi-xe3

Recently converted program from Delphi 2006 to XE3 and I have a problem with TidHttp.  Here is the code :

```
Result := '';
myCurrentTime := FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnss',now);

myParams := '<params>';
myParams := myParams + '<licence>' + '1234567890' + '</licence>'; 
myParams := myParams + '<activationcode>' + 'abcdef' + '</activationcode>'; 
myParams := myParams + '<devicename>' + 'aaa' + '</devicename>'; 
myParams := myParams + '<deviceid>' + 'bbb' + '</deviceid>'; 
myParams := myParams + '<devicetimestamp>' + myCurrentTime + '</devicetimestamp>';
myParams := myParams + psRequest;
myParams := myParams + '</params>';

myRequestStream := nil;
myResponseStream := nil;
myHTTP := nil;
myXMLDocument := nil;

finished := false;
myAttempts := cAttempts;

while finished = false do
begin
try
  myRequestStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  myResponseStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  myHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  myXMLDocument := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);

  myParams := mEncoder.Encode(myParams);

  myRequestStream.Write(myParams[1], Length(myParams));
  myRequestStream.Position := 0;

  myHTTP.Request.Method := 'POST';
  myHTTP.ReadTimeout := piTimeoutSeconds * 1000;
  myHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
  myHTTP.Request.ContentLength := myRequestStream.Size;
  myHTTP.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;

  myHTTP.Post(psUrl, myRequestStream, myResponseStream);
```

Following the post, I get the error 'Exception raised is invalid character in Base 64 string' - this is reported as a '{' in the error handling routine.

I have been scouring the web but can't find the answer.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You're only putting half your request details into the stream. In Delphi 2009, `string` became a Unicode type, where each character occupies two bytes. `Length` measures characters, while `TStream.Write` expects the number of bytes.

An easy solution is to change `myParams` to be an `AnsiString`.

Comment: It would be better to use a `TStringStream` or Indy's `WriteStringToStream()` function instead, both of which support Unicode strings and will convert them to bytes for you. Don't Ansify the code (especially if you ever plan on migrating to mobile, because `AnsiString` no longer exists at all in Embarcadero's mobile compilers).